# html5 / jQuery video preloader landing page

Tags: jquery, html, video, preloader

I'm working on a website that uses a html5 video tag as a background. 
[Awesome example of the site](http://jefferson.microdesign.nl/lawrence/)

As you can see the video is pretty heavy, and thus I'd like to have it preload. But not just preload as in:

```
<video id="video_background" controls="controls" preload="auto" loop>
```

Because this isn't compatible with the function 'autoplay'. And this being a background I want it to start without any user input.

What I'm looking for is some sort of plugin that creates a landingpage with a customizable preloading gif, that shows something like an 'enter' button upon completely loading all video divs.

I've got a great example here, the only downside is; it only loads images..
[Awesome example of an example](http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set a poster image on the background `video` element?

```
<video id="video_background" controls preload="auto" poster="video_background.jpg" autoplay>
...
</video>
```

Then you won't need a preloader as the browser will start playing the video as soon as it can.

Alternatively you can set an background image and start loading the video (via JavaScript or jQuery if your site already uses it) and when its status is akin to "can start playing" - hide the image and add the video instead.

Comment: Because I'm trying to avoid user input completely. This method requires controls.

Comment: How does it require user input?

Comment: Your edit explains using javascript to start the video. Wich would make 'controls' obsolete. However, if I wanted to add multiple video's (as this website is for a cinematographer) they will all be displaying an image. And only after having loaded will they play. Wich isn't exactly what I was looking for. A preloading landing page would load all these files, and make them available upon entering the site.

Comment: Then you can load all the files you require via AJAX.